# Error when using OUT parameters in datasnap servermethod

Tags: delphi, datasnap, delphi-10.1-berlin

I migrated a Datasnap server to XE 10.1 Berlin and now I get an error on the server when I invoke a servermethod with OUT parameters.

Object

```
  TBtwlControlePar=class
    xInDoc,
    xHandmatig,
    xStatus,
    xVerwacht,
    xAantal,
    xVerwerkt,
    xOnVerwerkt,
    xOnverwerktInDocument,
    xTotaalCustoms :Integer;
  end;

function TPWAdminMethods.DOC_BTWAH_Get2(pPeriode, pMaand, pSort,pSelop,pSelOntvangen,pSelToegewezen,pSelVerwerkt: integer; pSel: string; out pControlePar: TBTWLControlePar): TResult;
```

ServerMethod

```
tmpM := TPWAdminMethodsClient.Create (DMForm.DSConnection.DBXConnection, false);
```

Client

```
  FreeAndNil( fControlePar );
  tmpResult := tmpM.DOC_VATLH_Get2(Jaar,sort,SelOp,SelOntvangen,SelToegewezen,SelVerwerkt,fSelection,fControlePar);
```

When this method is fired the server gives an error on this last line

```
procedure TDSMethod.Invoke(MethodInstance: TObject;
  MethodValues: TDSMethodValues);
var
  RContext: TRttiContext;
  RType: TRttiType;
  Params: TArrayOfTValue;
begin
  Params := MethodValues.GetValues;
  RType := RContext.GetType(MethodInstance.ClassType);
  MethodValues.ReturnValue := RType.GetMethod(FMethodInfoHeader.NameFld.ToString).Invoke(MethodInstance, Params);
end;
```

[image: VAN and OUT argument must match parameter type exactly]

Is it impossible to use out parameters in Delphi Berling Datasnap without the use of DBXJson?

Comment: Are you sure that you use the *same* declaration for the class - not only a similar?

Comment: Yes, the problem also happens with a TStream object for example.

Comment: If you don't mind losing type safety you can simply change the `out` parameter to a pointer and do the conversion. After the conversion to `TObject`, do an `is` to check it's really the class you need it to be and then you can safely hardcast it to `TBtwlControlePar`

Answer (score 1):

This error message and the issue has been logged on Embarcadero's Quality Portal as RSP-14895. This was on 16May16 by someone else. That person stated "XE10 is OK".
Today (14Jun16) I added another test project to the issue. My test project is for the case of a VAR parameter. I have also provided a screenshot of the test project in action. My tests work on XE6 but fail on 10.1 Berlin.
I can't use DataSnap until this issue is fixed.
Please vote up the issue.